# How to replace string in json file which have a variable using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, replace

I have a json as below. Want to replace '$content' in the json with 'test/abc'

```
{
"$version": "0.0.1",
"description": "",
"content": {
    "url": "$content",
    "tag": {
        "version": "0.0.1",

    },
    "buildOptions": []
},
"env": "qa"}
```

I tried by converting it to JSON object but since there is a variable in that in gives me "ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid JSON primitive" error.

```
 $JsonData = Get-Content module.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

How can I replace $content with test/abc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can escape the `$` - either manually or with the `[regex]::Escape()` method. [*grin*]

if `$InStuff` contains your sample data in a here-string, then this will do the replacement ...

```
$InStuff -replace [regex]::Escape('$content'), 'test/abc'
```

hope that helps,
lee